# Objective-C - помогите с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, objective-c

```
NSString text = @"Начало текста [id23542234|Tony] конец текста.";
```

1. Необходимо из текста выше получить `id23542234` и `Tony` в переменные.
2. Необходимо в тексте выше заменить `[id23542234|Tony]` на `Tony`.

Вот набросал регулярное выражение. Правильное?

```
\\[[id]{2}[0-9]+\\|[a-z,а-я]+\\]
```

Как это кокретно на Objective-C реализовать?

P.S. Разобрался сам:
Регулярное выражение правильное.
Используем класс `NSRegularExpression`.
С помощью `regularExpressionWithPattern` находим вхождения.
А с помощью `stringByReplacingMatchesInString` заменяем в исходном тексте,

Answer (score 1):

Привет, Tony!

Вашу задачу можно решить следующим регулярным выражением:

```
/@".+?\[(id\d+)|\s\].+?/g
```

1. ищем *@"Начало текста [*
2. `.+?` означает, что мы "не жадно" берем текст, пока не встретим следующую инструкцию
3. `\[(id\d+)|\s\]` ищет строку вида *[id23542234|Tony]* (после которой идет любой текст)
4. `(id\d+)|` означает, что мы ищем *id* + *цифра, повторяющаяся сколько угодно раз* + *|*
5. нужный нам фрагмент оборачиваем в скобочки, это и будет искомой группой

Надеюсь, мой ответ Вам помог : )